# Як коротко перекласти "power series solution"

Tags: переклад, from-english, словосполучення

Треба перекласти "power series solution". Можна сказати *розв'язок у вигляді степеневого ряду*, але це досить розтягнуто, хотілось би мати стисліший переклад. Я думав на *розв'язок-степеневий ряд*. Але це сприймається як два слова, а мені потрібно, щоб це було наче одне складне поняття. Як тут бути?

Що треба перекласти: "Power series solution of differential equations".

Comment: *Степеневорядний розв'язок*? Мабуть, це вже занадто:)

Comment: а чому взагалі потрібно скорочувати? Розв'язок у вигляді степеневого ряду - цілком коректна та зрозуміла відповідь.

Comment: @Kvaz1r науковці тяжіють до коротких назв, і мова, яка надасть їм такі має більше шансів на використання.

Comment: Як математик, дозволю собі не погодитися з тим, що у математиці тяжіють до коротких назв, бо так можна взагалі загубити зміст. Тут потрібна точність. Взагалі-то, можна слово розв'язок відкинути і використати степеневий ряд або степеневе розвинення. Або 1) ряд за степенями x-x_0; 2) ряд Тейлора 2) ряд Маклорена 3) ряд Лорана. Але насправді усе залежить від змісту. Дайте усе речення.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найстисліший варіант: ряд розв'язку диференційного (чи диференціального) рівняння. Звісно це підходить у випадку, коли точно зрозуміло, що мова йде про степеневий ряд. Справа в тому, що в українських математичних текстах іменник „ряд“ часто не уточнюють прикметником степеневий, якщо це випливає зі змісту. В англійських таке рідко буває, бо series має значно більше значень, ніж наше слово ряд. Мені здається, що це якраз ваш випадок. Бо у вигляді рядів Фур'є шукають розв'язки рівнянь з частинними похідними. А тут, здається, звичайне дифрівняння. 
Інші варіанти: степеневий ряд розв’язку диференційного рівняння, 
степеневе розвинення розв’язку диференційного рівняння, розклад у ряд розв’язку диференційного рівняння, розвинення у ряд розв’язку диференційного рівняння. На жаль, у вашому випадку слово „розв'язок“ не викинеш, бо текст буде зовсім незрозумілим.Також можна вжити тейлорівський ряд чи маклоренівський ряд розв'язку.

Отже, найкоротшими є два варіанти: ряд розв'язку або трішки довший - розклад у ряд розв'язку. Такі новотвори „рядовий розв'язок“ чи „розв'язковий ряд“ будуть незрозумілими.